# Changing the back-end db from mysql to postgresql

Tags: php-5.6, postgresql-9.5

Actually I have an web app in php 5 with back-end as mysql it contains around 8 to 10 pages only and 8 tables. But now I have to change this to php with postgres db as of server availability.  Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Here i have attached few projects using this you can migrate from mysql to postgres

https://github.com/ggarri/mysql2psql

https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader